# RPG program error: Error MCH3601 was detected in file

Tags: rpgle, rpg

We have been facing a very strange issue with one of our RPGLE programs that bombs intermittently with the subjected error.

This happens specifically at a line where a write operation is performed to a subfile record format. I have debugged and checked all the values assigned to variables during runtime and could not find absolutely no issues. As per the https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/644069  IBM page, I can only assume that this might be related to the parameter definitions of the programs called within the RPG. But I have checked the parameters of each and every prototyped program call and everything seems to be in sync.

Can some one please guide on the direction to go to find out the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> But I have checked the parameters of each and every prototyped program
>   call

Assuming you're using prototypes properly, ie. there is one prototype defined in a separate source member and it is `/INCLUDE` into **BOTH** the caller and the callee...

Then prototype calls aren't the problem, as long as you're properly handling any `*OMIT` and `*NOPASS` parameters.

Look at any old style `CALL` or `CALLB` calls and anyplace you're not using prototypes properly...meaning there's a explicit PR coded in both caller & callee.

Note that you it's not just old-style calls made by the program that bombs, it's calls made anywhere down the call chain.

And if the program is repeatedly called with LR=*OFF or without reclaiming resources, then it could be any old style calls up the call chain also.

Lastly, old style calls include any made by CL or CLLE programs.

Good luck!